# Value not showing in console Node js express-hbs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nodejs-server

I want to store the data to the database but the value is not receiving from hbs file.
I want to create a signup page where user can enter fullname, email, password, repassword but it is not even showing in the console.why does that happening?

I want to learn express NodeJS and MongoDB. But I am stuck with the CRUD operations

**users.js -router**

```
> var express = require('express'); var router = express.Router(); const
        > userReg= require("../models/data")
        > 
        > 
        > /* GET users listing. */ router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {  
        > res.render('signup'); }); router.post('/signup',async(req, res)=>{  
        > console.log(req.body.name)   const name= req.body.name;   const email=
        > req.body.email;   const password= req.body.password;   const
        > repassword= req.body.repassword; 
        > 
        >   const user = await userReg.create({
        >     name,
        >     email,
        >     password,
        >     repassword   });   res.send("Ok bro"); }); module.exports = router;


  **Signup.hbs**

>     <section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #2779e2;">
>       <div class="container h-100">
>         <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
>           <div class="col-xl-9">
>     
>             <h1 class="text-white mb-4">Sign Up</h1>
>             <form action="/home" method="post">
>             <div class="card" style="border-radius: 15px;">
>               <div class="card-body">
>     
>                 <div class="row align-items-center pt-4 pb-3">
>                   <div class="col-md-3 ps-5">
>     
>                     <h6 class="mb-0">Full name</h6>
>     
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="col-md-9 pe-5">
>     
>                     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="name" />
>     
>                   </div>
>                 </div>
>     
>                 <hr class="mx-n3">
>     
>                 <div class="row align-items-center py-3">
>                   <div class="col-md-3 ps-5">
>     
>                     <h6 class="mb-0">Email address</h6>
>     
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="col-md-9 pe-5">
>     
>                     <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="example@example.com" name="email"/>
>     
>                   </div>
>                 </div>
>     
>                 <hr class="mx-n3">
>     
>                 <div class="row align-items-center py-3">
>                   <div class="col-md-3 ps-5">
>     
>                     <h6 class="mb-0">Password</h6>
>     
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="col-md-9 pe-5">
>     
>                     <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="password"/>
>                   </div>
>                 </div>
>     
>                 <hr class="mx-n3">
>     
>                 <div class="row align-items-center py-3">
>                   <div class="col-md-3 ps-5">
>     
>                     <h6 class="mb-0">Confirm Password</h6>
>     
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="col-md-9 pe-5">
>     
>                     <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="repassword" />
>                   </div>
>                 </div>
>                 <hr class="mx-n3">
>     
>                 <div class="px-5 py-4">
>                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SignUp</button>
>                 </div>
>     
>               </div>
>             </div>
>         </form>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </section>
```

**model-schema**

```
> const mongoose = require("mongoose");
>     
>     const signupSchema=mongoose.Schema({
>         name:{
>             type: String,
>             required:[true,"Please fill the field"]
>         },
>         email:{
>             type: String,
>             required:[true,"Please fill the field"]
>         },
>         password:{
>             type: String,
>             required:[true,"Please fill the field"]
>         },
>         repassword:{
>             type: String,
>             required:[true,"Please fill the field"]
>         }, 
>     });
>     
>     module.exports = mongoose.model("register",signupSchema);
```

help me out this I am a beginner, I am stuck for 2 days. Can anybody guide me or suggest me some tutorial for the MongoDB connection and crud operations in node js express.

Comment: `action="/home"` - where is the `/home` endpoint?